# Not able to localize the datepicker using moment.locale()

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I used `moment.locale()` for localize the datepicker depending on the language which user select.

1) When I use global instance of moment (Not injecting the moment in a component) and calling  `moment.locales()` its returning as

```
["en", "de", "es", "fr", "it", "ja", "nl", "pt-br", "ko", "zh-cn", "zh-tw"]
```

After that I tried to set the `moment.locale("fr")`, it is working fine as expected.

2) When I am using local instance of moment (Injecting moment in the component) and calling  `moment.locales()` its returning as

```
 ["en"]
```

After that I tried to set the `moment.locale('fr')`, it is always set as `'en'`.

The same issue is happening for me when I try to get the timezones.

1) `moment.tz.names()` is returning all the timezone name as an array if I am using global instance of moment.

2) `moment.tz.names()` is returning `undefined`  if I am using local instance of moment.

Please help me to sort out this issue.

Comment: Can you share your angular code? Anyway see the [_Where to use_](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/) section of the momentjs docs, maybe you can find useful info there.

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/urish/angular-moment?

Comment: @VincenzoC   moment.locale(locale.getActiveLanguage()); it is used to set for localization

Comment: @lin No. I am using moment.js

Comment: Could you please add a fiddle to reproduce your problem?